# URL String cant run on android 11

Tags: android, string, url

when i run onClickListener to open URL String on android 11 it runs fine.

However, when I try it on android 11, the URL String doesn't work and it doesn't redirect the app to the specified link.

What is the solution to this problem?

This is my code:

```
    img_wa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                String mrk = merek.getText().toString();
                String bran = brand.getText().toString();
                String hrg = harga.getText().toString();
                String pesan = "Apakah Produk Masih Ada ?";
                PackageManager packageManager = getApplication().getPackageManager();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+ "+6285210745920" +"&text="
                        + URLEncoder.encode("[Konfirmasi Produk]"+"\n"+"\n"+mrk+"("+bran+")"+"\n"+hrg+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+pesan, "UTF-8");
                i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                    startActivity(i);
                }else {

                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR WHATSAPP",e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: So you are asking why 3rd party application didn't react on some undocumented uri?  moreover you didn't wrote what you are getting and there is no log statment if `i.resolveActivity(...)` returns null

Answer (score 0):

you need to register the package name in your manifest

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />
</queries>
```